# Updating multiple values from one table to another with a matching key

Tags: mysql

Here I have two tables -

```
Table = blockCount
________________________
blockNo   houseCount
________________________
A-1         14
A-2         28
A-3         20
B-1         32
D-2         18
.
.
etc
___________________________________________

Table = Report
______________________
blockNo    houseCount
______________________
A-1         null
A-2         null
A-3         null
B-1         null
D-2         null
.
.
etc
```

Task is to update Report with values from blockCount table matching the column blockNo

I have exhausted my limited knowledge of SQL and reasearched but not sure how to ask the question

Seems like a join but ...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
UPDATE Report
INNER JOIN blockCount
ON blockCount.blockNo = Report.blockNo
SET Report.houseCount = blockCount.houseCount;
```

**Note:** Only the matching rows in Report table will have the corresponding `houseCount` value from the `blockCount` table's `houseCount` column

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/547f4/1/0)

Comment: When one can communicate through `comment` for the **betterment** `down voting` shows the impatience. Thanks for your point by the way.

Comment: THANK YOU.  I had tried so many ideas that I was tangled up in my underwear and couldn't get a reasonable perspective on the approach. Sort of like 'writers' block'. Or the head slap.   All programmers know the feeling.

Comment: ha ha! XD By the way, Did you get it?